# Is this tree healthy?

Tags: conifers

[image]

We have this tree in our yard, is this mold? Is it treatable?[image][image][image][image]

Answer (score 1):

Mold is not a problem, I think this is old age.  The cambium is in big trouble with the separation of the bark and it appears lots of larva are to be had by woody wood peckers.

We need a few more pictures, your zone or where you live on this planet, pictures of leaves, picture of the base of the trunk and the soil line, picture of your entire tree, how close is this tree to public right of ways, your home?

This could be a partial die out of the cambium.  Hopefully the rest of the circumference of cambium (thin, fragile, vascular system right beneath the bark) is healthy and it should be able to support the tree just fine.

This tree might be okay or it could be a widow maker.  Please send more information, thanks!

Comment: Looks like wood worms to me as well.

Comment: Actually those holes were made by the wood peckers going after the 'worms' or rather larvae (beetles?)  I think the bark separated and the tree has thickened to replace the bark it needs for protection.  The birds go after live stuff that is in live tissue.  That tells me this tree might be just fine.  Really need to see a picture of the entire tree.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I've uploaded more photos, I hope that gives a better picture of the tree :)